# return partial view from async method

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, async-await, partial-views

I've an async action method that return a partial view.
this action method called from a function with ajax.

my problem : when this method invoked every thing looks good except returned partial view.
I got error 500.

this is my action method Code :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeStateGroup(int[] lstCustomerServiceId, int newState)
{
    int _counter = 0;
    try
    {           
            var _isOk = await CommonFunctions.ChangeState(_customerServiceId, _stateId, string.Empty);

            if (_isOk)
            {
                //------do somthing
            }
        }
        TempData[MyAlerts.SUCCESS] = string.Format("succeed Operation {0}", _counter);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        TempData[MyAlerts.ERROR] = string.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    return PartialView("_AlertsPartial");
}
```

and this is my jquery Code:

```
function postCustomerChangeStateGroup(lstCustomersId) {
    
    var arrCustomersId = lstCustomersId.split(',');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Customer/ChangeStateGroup",
        data: {
            lstCustomerServiceId: arrCustomersId,
            newState: $("#fk_state").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.indexOf("error") !== -1) {
                $("#inlineAlert_Wrapper").append(data);
            }
            else {
                getCustomerReport();
                $('#modal-container').modal('toggle');
                $("#alert_Wrapper").append(data);
            }
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert("An Error Accoured: " + errMsg);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Partial views cannot be asynchronous in ASP.NET pre-Core. You *can* have asynchronous partial views in ASP.NET Core.

So, your options are:

1. Update to ASP.NET Core.
2. Remove the asynchronous code and make it synchronous instead.

Comment: ohh GOD. how bad, its expensive. but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 means the error inside of the action.It maybe because ot the empty input parameters. Check them in debugger and if they are empty,
try to use application/json content type,sometimes it works better

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Customer/ChangeStateGroup",
        data: JSON.stringify( {
            lstCustomerServiceId: arrCustomersId,
            newState: $("#fk_state").val()
        }),
        success: function (data) {
        ....
```

create viewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
 public int[] lstCustomerServiceId {get; set;}
public  int newState {get; set;}
}
```

and fix the action

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ChangeStateGroup([FromBody] ViewModel model)
```

Comment: I`m sure my input isn`t empty. but I`ll try your way and inform you. thanx